# MS Excel macro for not counting weekends?

Tags: excel

**Q:** how can I create a macro (any ideas?) for the "OVERDUE" column?

It should be "Y" if the:

```
CREATED column+DAYS column is YOUNGER than the current date.
```

It should be "N" if not.

**But: weekends not needed to be counted..**

so if ex.:

- the "CREATED" is "8/10/2013 22:38" - Saturday so weekend and the "DAYS" is 2, then the addition of the two should be: 8/13/2013 24:00
- if the "CREATED" is "8/16/2013 11:26" - Friday, so weekday and the "DAYS" is 2, then the addition of the two should be: 8/20/2013 13:34

Example:

```
today is: 8/13/2013 10:25

CREATED     DAYS    OVERDUE
8/10/2013 22:38     2   Y
8/12/2013 11:26     2   N
```

Because:

```
8/10/2013 22:38 + 2 days is younger then 8/13/2013 10:25, so "OVERDUE" needs to be "Y"
8/12/2013 11:26 + 2 days is older then 8/13/2013 10:25, so "OVERDUE" needs to be "N"
```

Comment: Maybe you should look into the [weekday function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/weekday-HP005209336.aspx) of Excel. You don't need a macro for that...

Comment: macro is needed for it.. not function, sorry..

Comment: still - you can use Excel functions in your macro via WorksheetFunction

Comment: `It should be "Y" if the CREATED column+DAYS column is older than the current date` **contradicts** `8/12/2013 11:26 + 2 days is older then 8/13/2013 10:25, so "BAD" needs to be "N"`

Comment: you say: weekends not needed to be counted? is it if the *created* is weekend ? or the *created* + *days* if the new date is a weekend? or if today is a weekend? please explain.

Comment: yea the weekend thing doesn't make sense either. OP's revision required.

Comment: You have updated this question many times now, please next time put some effort before submitting a question.

Comment: also, what are your locale settings?

Comment: OK, so I UPDATED it again, to be clear, Thanks :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using IF and compare the date with NOW() ?

```
=IF( (A2+B2)<NOW(),"Y","N")
```

(okey, I will check your updated question and make new inputs here...)

**used formulas:**

```
=WEEKDAY(B2)        
=IF(D2=7,1,IF(OR(D2=5,D2=6),2,0))   
=B2+C2+F2   
=IF(G2<NOW(),"Y","N")
```

[image: something like this?]